# I don't vs I can't

Tags: differences, conditionals, sleep

what's the difference with "If I drink coffee, I don't sleep. vs If I drink coffee, I can't sleep."

Comment: There is, in practice, little difference.   Examples can be found of contexts in which “don’t” is different.  For example, if someone needs to stay awake for a purpose, and uses coffee as the stimulant, ‘don’t’ is preferable:  s/he’s not trying to sleep.  In reply to someone offering coffee late in the evening, either would do but ‘can’t’ is stronger.  A picky realist might say that Since nobody can try to go to sleep, it makes no sense to say you ‘can’t’.  But we do say that and understand the sense of the helpless desperation.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

"Can't" means that you do not perform the action of sleeping because you don't have the ability to.  "Don't" would mean just that you don't perform the action, but it doesn't say anything about your ability to.  Maybe you still have the ability to sleep after coffee, but you just always choose not to.

In this sentence, simply choosing not to sleep after having coffee all the time is unlikely, so "can't" and "don't" mean about the same thing here

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!